# Is it often assumed that the matrix will be decomposed is real for The Singular Value Decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

I'm learning Linear Algebra with Applications 8th Edition by Steve J Leon.
The Theorem about my question is the following:

> Theorem 6.5.1 The SVD Theorem
>
> If $A$ is an $m × n$ matrix, then $A$ has a singular value decomposition.

The proof given is the following:

> Proof
>
> $A^TA$ is a symmetric $n × n$ matrix. Therefore, its eigenvalues are all real and it has an orthogonal diagonalizing matrix ...

Why are eigenvalues of $A^TA$ all real here? I know that eigenvalues of a REAL symmetric matrix are all real, but I cannot find any assumption that A is a real matrix from context. Is it often assumed that the matrix will be decomposed is REAL for The Singular Value Decomposition? At the forefront of this section is "In many applications, ...", is that assumed the matrix is REAL?

Comment: If you'd like, exchange the transpose with the conjugate transpose, we get a Hermitian matrix instead, which also only has real eigenvalues.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks, Arthur. But in this book, conjugate transpose of A is always written as $A^H$ and I'm sure that it's not a typo.

Comment: It seems like the author is implicitly assuming that $A$ has real entries, but this should be stated explicitly. (Perhaps it is stated at the beginning of the chapter or something.)

Comment: @littleO I think so but I cannot find it is stated explicitly somewhere but at the forefront of this section is "In many applications, ...". is that assumed the matrix has real entries?

Comment: Yes, the author is implicitly assuming that  has real entries. Since there is $"|| Ax ||^2=x^TA^TAx"$ in the proof later. If A has complex entries, it should be $"|| Ax ||^2=x^HA^HAx"$.